# How to change keymap to add selection caret on Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

How can I change the keymap to add selection caret on Sublime Text?

The default is <kbd>ctrl + left mouse</kbd>, I want to change to <kbd>alt + left mouse</kbd>, like PhpStorm's keymap.

Comment: Which is it, ST2 or ST3?

Comment: Sublime Text 3 buddy

Comment: And what OS are you using?

Comment: windows and linux buddy

Answer (score 4):

In Sublime Text, *sublime-keymap* files are used for keyboard shortcuts and *sublime-mousemap* files for mouse actions. Your question is obviously about mouse shortcuts, but there are also some keyboard-related commands to add carets, so I will also talk about them.

## Mousemap

Open your User mousemap at

*Packages/User/Default (Linux/Windows).sublime-mousemap* (*)

Add the entry:

```
{
    "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt"],
    "press_command": "drag_select",
    "press_args": {"additive": true}
},
```

Change the button and modifiers for more tuning.

You can also use the lines and columns variants:

```
    "press_args": {"by": "lines", "additive": true}
    "press_args": {"by": "columns", "additive": true}
```

to select whole lines, or by columns. If you click without dragging in column selection, a caret will simply be added, so you can setup the columns variant, and only use the column selection when you need.

For more examples and variants, have a look at the default mousemap at

*Packages/Default/Default (Linux/Windows).sublime-mousemap*

(*) To access it directly from Sublime Text you can use the plugin [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer)

If you prefer your own commands/shortcuts, create a entry in some *sublime-commands* file:

```
{
    "caption": "Preferences: Mouse Bindings - Default",
    "command": "open_file", "args":
    {
        "file": "${packages}/Default/Default ($platform).sublime-mousemap",
        "contents": "[\n\t$0\n]\n"  // start with "[]" if new file is created
    }
}
```

and an entry in your keymap file (pick the shortcut you want)

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+m"], "command": "open_file", "args": {"file": "${packages}/User/Default ($platform).sublime-mousemap", "contents": "[\n\t$0\n]\n"} }
```

## Keymap

Apart from the caret duplication that happens when you select multiple occurences, there are commands to duplicate the caret on the lines above or below.

Open your User keymap file and add the entries:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
```

with the shortcuts you want.

## Caveats

In Sublime Text, there may be multiple shortcuts per command and adding a User shortcut does not deactivate Default shortcuts. If you want to deactivate some annoying default mouse behaviors, for example, you will have to:

- copy the Default mousemap from your unzipped Default package (PackageResourceViewer does not seem to be able to extract it, so do it manually, by adding .zip to the sublime-package if required)
- paste it to your **Default** package folder
- uncomment the entries you want to ignore